# How can I access a resource when running an SBT runTask?

Tags: scala, resources, classpath, sbt

I've got an XML file that I need to read from the classpath in order to load some test data for my project with DBUnit when running a custom runTask in SBT.

The XML file is located in /src/main/resources and is copied properly to the /target/scala_2.8.1/classes during the build, but I get a MalformedURLException when trying to access it.

The weird thing is, I can access the file when this data loading functionality was part of my Scala specs unit tests.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, what _is_ the URL you are passing?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I used getClass.getResourceAsStream() in early initialiser. Had to specify the class explicitly with Class.forName() to solve it: `Class.forName(<class name>).getResourceAsStream("/data.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

If the error is saying that the URL is malformed, it's probably true.
Here's a code I use to grab file from resource during test:

```
def copyFileFromResource(source: String, dest: File) {
  val in = getClass.getResourceAsStream(source)
  val reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(in))
  val out = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(dest))
  var line: String = null
  line = reader.readLine
  while (line != null) {
    out.println(line)
    line = reader.readLine
  }
  in.close
  out.flush
}
```